# Wondering about materials

Tags: mars, materials, planet

I am currently designing a Revit project on the planet Mars I was wondering what a wall on a base like structure need to consist of to protect its from the planet atmosphere.

any thoughts ?

regards,
Matt

Comment: Tissue paper? Cling wrap? What aspect of the near-vacuum Martian atmosphere are you trying to protect against?

Comment: The base I'm designing is at the base of Ceraunius Tholus a 115km wide  ,22km high volcano in Northwest Tharsis at 240 N,970 W, any thoughts?

Comment: that volcano's probably been extinct for billions of years, it's not likely to affect the nearby atmospheric conditions.

Comment: ok then referring back lets just say cold at night and we have to acquire the dust storms and radiation what are your thoughts on that for material wise?

Comment: My thoughts are that your question is underspecified.

Answer (score 2):

Amundsen–Scott South Pole Station is a building designed to withstand at least -80 C, quite close to the temperature on Mars in the night time. The materials used for this edifice on legs can also be used on the red planet. The atmosphere there is different being ridiculously thin, and mainly composed of CO2, but it is thick enough to prevent outgassing, for most materials. This is not vacuum.

[image]

[Amundsen–Scott South Pole Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amundsen%E2%80%93Scott_South_Pole_Station)

Comment: The radiation is a problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_Mars#:~:text=Difficulties%20and%20hazards%20include%20radiation,of%20water%2C%20and%20cold%20temperatures). One meter of rock is needed for shielding the inhabitants of such shelters. This means that they will have to live underground in pressurized containers much like the Space Station but buried at least 1 m under the surface. A realistic construction on Mars will be nearly invisible. Another problem is the fine dust which is poisonous.